# How do I make <a> tags with a class unclickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, anchor

I have some parent nav items with children and I don't need the parent items to be clickable.

They look like this:

```
<a href="parent">Parent Item</a>
```

Is there anyway to target the `<a>` tags with the specific class of `.parent` and make them unclickable?

Comment: @RobG If it was that easy, I would. This is built on Ning which comes with its own parent links that you can't take out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
  $(function () {
    $('a.parent').on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

If anyone interested in Pure CSS solution *(As this question is tagged as CSS)* than you can use [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```
a[href="parent"] {
    cursor: default;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xUJVQ/)

---

As far as support goes

[image]

<sup>Credits: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)</sup>

Comment: This is great, but I forgot to mention that I have child elements under the parent elements and when I input this code, the child elements (i.e. submenu) doesn't come down anymore.

Comment: @Desi Obviously they won't as you are preventing the default behavior, consider altering your script

Comment: @Mr.Alien : +1 , cleaner...`css` always preferred over `jQ`!! :)

Comment: @Mr. Alien Sorry, I wasn't trying to be a smart ass. I do appreciate your answer and I learned something new in CSS today.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using the jQuery library, it's just as easy without it:

```
var disabled = document.querySelector('.parent');
disabled.addEventListener('click', function(e) {e.preventDefault();}, false);
```

Comment: Hehe, thanks. There are so many nice additions to JS these days (like `querySelector`) that I'm even more keen to avoid jQuery. What do you think of my CSS solution?

Comment: That might be nice for older browsers but would be overkill for latest ones, I've provided a simple CSS solution, that does the job in single line :)

Comment: Fair enough, though support only for IE11 and above makes it seem a bit soon to rely on `pointer-events` to me ... although it depends on the site, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Another pure CSS option would be to overlay the link with an absolutely positioned "cover":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style media="all">

.parent {position: relative; z-index: -1;}
.parent:after {content: ""; position: absolute; top:0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://google.com" class="parent">Disabled Link</a>
<a href="http://google.com">Normal Link</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a listener on every `.parent`, you can put a single listener on the body. The following will work in every browser in use without any library support:

```
function stopClickOnParentClass(evt) {
  var el = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
  if (/(^|\s)parent(\s|$)/.test(el.className)) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

then:

```
<body onclick="stopClickOnParent(event);" …>
```

You could also make the class dynamic by passing it to the function and building the regular expression from it.